# How to add label into a horizontal grouped bar graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some inquires about how to create a labelled horizontal grouped bar graph. I am attempting to use a DataFrame to make the graph as shown below. (The image came from an online source that I found earlier on but did not show code on how to do it)

[image: The intended graph I want to achieve.]

However, the problem is that there is no code showing how to do it and most of the codes have been made outdated after new updates to the Python system and the associated libraries. What is the code I need to obtain such a graph with labels displayed at each bar graphs? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See:

- https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html
- https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barh.html
- https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html

The result of combining these references is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
men_means = [20, 34, 30, 35, 27]
women_means = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]

y = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.barh(y - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
rects2 = ax.barh(y + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')

ax.set_xlabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_yticks(y)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()

ax.bar_label(rects1, label_type='center')
ax.bar_label(rects2, label_type='center')
```

[image]